# how to update row

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:-

TABLE A

```
CODE          DESC
----          ----
A001          BLACK
12AA          SOFT
B001          GREY
13SW          ANTIQUE
B011          BROWN
23WQ          HARD
```

TABLE B

```
NO      MODEL         COLOR     FINISH
--      -----         -----     ------
01      QWER          A001      12AA
02      ASDF          B011      13SW
03      ZXCV          B001      12AA
04      POIU          A001      23WQ
```

I wish to hv an output like this using SQL:-

```
NO      MODEL         COLOR     FINISH
--      -----         -----     ------
01      QWER          BLACK      SOFT
02      ASDF          BROWN      ANTIQUE
03      ZXCV          GREY       SOFT
04      POIU          BLACK      HARD
```

Comment: this is called a SELECT not an UPDATE

Comment: which database system? update from JOIN is different for each system. Unless of course you *did* mean SELECT instead of UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Research SQL `join`s:

```
select b.no, b.model, a1.desc as 'color', a.desc as 'finish' 
from tableb b
inner join tablea as a
on b.finish = a.code
inner join tabla as a1
on b.color = a1.code
```

This query 'merges' the two tables based on a common indentifier (in this the `code`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to join two times against `table_a`:

```
select b.no, b.model, a1.desc, a2.desc
  from table_b b 
 inner join table_a a1 on (b.color = a1.code)
 inner join table_a a2 on (b.finish = a2.code)
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote. I think it's what OP's looking for... Anyway, if there is something wrong with it, I will gladly correct it. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for being correct, although it would be better to alias the columns and use LEFT joins

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :)

```
SELECT TEMP1.NO,TEMP1.MODEL,TEMP1.COLOR,TEMP2.FINISH FROM 
(SELECT B.NO, B.MODEL, A.CODE,A.DESC AS COLOR FROM A,B WHERE A.CODE=B.COLOR)TEMP1,   
(SELECT B.NO, B.MODEL, A.CODE,A.DESC AS FINISH FROM A,B WHERE A.CODE=B.FINISH)TEMP2
WHERE TEMP1.NO=TEMP2.NO
```